# DocuSign API - Creating a document - How do you enable links for HTML content in the document?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add a document to my DocuSign envelope using the REST API.

This document is being added by converting an HTML document to a base64 string and setting this string as the value for the DocumentBase64 property of the document (See https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#envelopeDefinition).

My concern is that the HTML document has some links, but those links are not clickable in the DocuSign signing session. Is there any way to allow for links to be clickable/navigatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security concerns, links in documents sent to DocuSign are disabled.
This applies to all document source types including links in HTML, PDF, Word, and other document source types.

If you want to provide optional documents to the signers or other recipients for them to potentially look at while they're signing a document, there are several options:

1. Use [Supplemental documents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents#supplemental-documents). These are separate documents that are included in the envelope for the recipient to (optionally) refer to.
2. Use [Smart Sections](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview). This enables you to mark sections of a document as optional. They're then only shown if the recipient clicks on them.